# forward https request with client certificate

Tags: apache, https, certificate, client, tunnel

I want to achieve to forward / tunnel a https request controlled by a specific domain name directly to a server behind.

For example:

request (domain1.com) -> [incoming gateway] --tunnel--> [https server1.intern]
request (domain2.com) -> [incoming gateway] --tunnel--> [https server2.intern]

Usually I'm doing this with apache mod proxy, but when using client certificate we must tunnel the ssl connection directly to the server behind the incoming gateway to avoid a man in the middle attack. Am I right so far? How could I resolve that issue?